# Сократить количество запросов к БД

Tags: php, mysql, оптимизация

Достался мне проект, да не простой, а запутанный - во время выполнения он обращается к таблице 70-120 раз, в зависимости от типа запроса. И это не считая других служебных запросов типа настроек и прочего.
Помимо проблемы рефакторинга этого хлама, встаёт другая, более интересная: данные нужны именно во время работы, нельзя подгрузить в конце, в начале тоже, т.к. записей в таблице несколько тысяч, никогда не знаешь какие 100 понадобятся в этот раз.
Кэширование тоже не то, чтобы подходит - все записи довольно регулярно обновляются и на удивление равномерно используются.
Все эти запросы вида: `SELECT something FROM table WHERE id = integer`.

Как это разрулить и оптимизировать хотя бы немного?
Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Столь мелкие запросы, не так уж сильно и загрузят базу. Без создания этих данных во временном хранилище и его обновлении - не обойтись, но как написано в ответе от @retvizan - не стоит этого делать преждевременно. В любом случае подойдите логически: в момент времени вам нужна информация, а значит вы будете ее запрашивать в это время... из кэша, базы не важно. Но учтите что при частой смене данных, вам кэш так же прийдется постоянно обновлять, что создаст нагрузку на базу не меньше, но на приложение больше. (учитывая что запросы простейшие с одним условием по ключевому полю).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имхо, вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией, а это "корень всех зол". 
Само по себе большое кол-во запросов не есть плохо, да и кэширование в некоторых случаях может дать обратный эффект. Начать нужно с создания искусственной нагрузки, аналогичной ожидаемой в будущем и поиске узких мест при этом.

Answer (score 1):

Из простого - сделать индекс по id и перенести таблицу (если mysql) в память.
Из правильного (на мой взгляд) - Redis/memcache для хранения данных. Несколько тысяч записей это очень мало для современных объемов памяти, легко поместится.

Comment: Манипуляции с БД ограничены, да и я с ней на Вы (но главное что БД не поменяешь просто так), но этот план активируется, если больше ничего не придумаю.  
Вопрос о месте не стоит - его полно, другое дело что каждый запрос порождает 100 запросов к БД. Десяток юзеров выдержать легко, но планируется далеко не десяток...

Comment: Редис/мемкеш тем и хороши что легко встраиваются между приложением и БД. Логика простая - если не нашли в локальной памяти - лезем в кэш, не нашли там - запрашиваем в БД (обновляя кэш). При апдейте в базе инвалидируем/обновляем кэш. Все быстро и просто.

Comment: О редиске я сразу подумал, да и кэш есть. Но как я сказал БД лучше модифицировать в последнюю очередь. Придётся, конечно, если лучшего не будет.

Answer (score 1):

В запросах по первичному ключу нет никаких проблем. Прикручивать монгу, реддис, мемкеш не имеет смысла в случае сложного разветвленного процесса. 
Первая оптимизация - это дедубликация запросов. В сложных процессах, написанных кривыми руками бывает. 
Второе - оптимизация алгоритма. Иногда, когда обсасываешь задачу долго, приходит понимание того, что если сделать процесс немного наоборот, то получится проще и быстрее. Т.е. пока вы не разберетесь основательно - зачем это было так сделано, вы не сможете проводить оптимизацию. Берите редактор и рисуйте процессы, алгоритмы, логику. Легкого пути не будет.
Ну или если у вас есть все спеки - напишите заново (:
З.Ы. я надеюсь с индексами и настройками бд у вас все впорядке?

Answer (score 0):

Если эти однообразные запросы вызываются в цикле и различаются только параметром ID, то можно переделать на один запрос. Надо только накопить айдишники в массиве и потом использовать условие IN().
Псевдокод:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $ids[] = $row['id'];
  // ... другая полезная работа в цикле ...
}
// одним запросом получим всё
$s = implode(',', $ids);
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT something FROM table WHERE id IN($s)");
```

Comment: Рекомендую перечитать условие - данные нужны именно во время запроса, копить их нельзя, ибо потом они не нужны. Будь так просто, я бы и вопроса не задавал. Наверное.

Comment: Если все не так просто, надо сделать чтобы стало просто )

Comment: Мудрые слова, мой друг, правда не всегда получается упростить до простого. Ну или для этого нужно слишком сильно попыхтеть :)

Comment: А кому сейчас легко? Из вашей постановки непонятно почему нельзя "копить". Потому что вывод вперемешку с получнием данных или почему? Так-то 70-120 айдишников не кажутся большим грузом. Нет объяснения — нет рецепта.

Comment: Так я написал - запрашивает значение и обрабатывает его (где-то вставляет как `printf`, где-то парсит или сериализует) и так много раз.
Вывод един, но код старый, некоторые моменты ещё для PHP3 писались, так что там адова хрень.
Если придётся переписывать (а, видимо, придётся), то лучше сразу наметить как лучше сделать, поэтому спросил тут.

Comment: Вангую, что речь идет о чем-то вроде дерева посредством adjacency list, где каждая следующая итерация зависит от результатов предыдущей. Но даже в этом случае можно использовать результаты "кучкой", чтобы запрашивать не каждый узел, а целый слой.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22677/discussion-between-thedoctor-and-artoodetoo).